# Dummy Shell in C get bugged after closing external process

Tags: c, shell, fork, exec

I am writing a shell for an assignment in C. My only problem now is that when I call an external program with execvp() and then close is using CTRL + C, any further commands that I send are printed after the prompt not before it. I made an dummy program that is just an infinite loop to test this.

So after closing this program if I try and run a program that doesn't exist, it will print out
MINISHELL (cwd) $: and then a blank line
and then it will print my error message saying that I have entered a program that does not exist and then it will not print a prompt since it already has. So It ends with an empty new line and it appears that the program has not ended but it actually has.

It ONLY does this after I have closed a non terminating program with CTRL + C. Otherwise it works fine executing programs. Am I not using close() somewhere to close a file descriptor? I am not sure. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include "minishell.h"


void intHandler(int sig)
{
    my_char('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    int pid = 0;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    char cwd[1024];
    char** input;

    while (1)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, intHandler);

        my_str("MINISHELL:");

        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
            my_str(cwd);

        else
        {
            my_str("Error in current directory");
            return -1;
        }

        my_str(" $: ");
        n = read(0, s, 256);
        s[n] = '\0';

        if (n > 1)
        {
            input = my_str2vect(s);
            if (my_strcmp(input[0], "cd") == 0)
            {
                /*CHANGE DIRECTORY*/
                if (input[1] != '\0')
                {
                    if (chdir(input[1]) < 0)
                        my_str("MINISHELL: Error in path. Make sure the directory exists.\n");
                }

                else
                    my_str("MINISHELL: Error. No directory specified.\n");
            }

            else if (my_strcmp(input[0], "help") == 0)
            {
                /*HELP*/
                my_str("\nMINISHELL COMMANDS:\n\ncd *directory\nChanges the current working directory to *directory\n\nexit\nExits the minishell\n\nhelp\nPrints a help message listing the built in commands\n\n");
            }

            else if (my_strcmp(input[0], "exit") == 0)
            {
                /*EXIT*/
                my_str("Thank you for using MINISHELL\n");
                exit(0);
            }

            else if (input[0] != NULL)
            {
                /*EXECUTE AN EXTERNAL PROGRAM*/
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
                    my_str("MINISHELL: Error forking\n");

                else if (pid > 0)
                {
                    wait(NULL);
                }

                else
                {
                    if (execvp(input[0], input) < 0)
                    {
                        my_str("MINISHELL: Error. Program does not exist in current directory.\n");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        exit(0);
                        close(0);   
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                my_str("MINISHELL: Error reading command. Type help to see available commands.");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually let me rephrase that. You only need to call `exit(0)` after the `execvp()` fails because the process will be running the exec program and not your code.

Comment: So I only want exit(0) inside my if statement if it fails?

Comment: I'm explaining it poorly but yes the `exit(0)` needs to be inside of the `if` with your error message. When you run `execvp()` and it suceeds, it replaces the process with the new program and never returns to your code. If it fails, then you need to exit the process you created with `fork()` still.

Comment: Alright I changed my exit(0) placement. It didn't help the problem and I don't think it stems from there. It only happens if I close a program that executed properly.

Comment: No, that's a problem unrelated to your main question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect that the error message will always print before your prompt. The forked process is running in parallel with your main program. The order in which the output to stdout from the two programs occur is dependent upon how the OS scheduler runs the processes.

I think most real shells like bash actually do the check for the file existing in the main process before doing the `fork()`. Alternatively you could use `pipe()` and manually redirect the output. Then you can enforce flushing the entire contents before doing your prompt.

Comment: how would I check for the file existing before forking?

Comment: Well if you only allow for it in the current directory, you'd have to use `readdir()` to find it and verify the user has perms to execute it. You will still likely run into problems with output from the program getting mixed with your prompts though. I think you'll have to use pipes to prevent it entirely.